# What is the best method to associate customers to TFS work items and bugs?

Tags: tfs, agile, tfs-workitem

I'm wondering what the best method is so associate TFS work items and bugs to customers so we can track what customers are waiting on particular bug or work item.

We have lots of customers using our product. If customers find a bug or request a feature, we would like to be able to associate that customer against a work item (There could also be multiple customers waiting on the same work item).

At the moment we are just creating a new task for a work item and assigning it a custom state called "Notify Customer" and including the client names in the title.

Can anyone think of a better method or have any suggestions on how they do this?

**Update:**

Decided to go with the tags for the customer name using the format "Client: *Name*". Then create a query for each customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

**A:** administrative access permitting, you can consider modifying the work item type using the `Tools>Process Editor>Work Item Types>Open WIT from Server` feature added to Visual Studio by the [TFS Power Tools extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to include a custom text field which can then be used to enter the affected customer's name. If your customers are actually TFS users themselves you can mirror the functionality of the `AssignedTo` work item field. The latter `(AssignedTo)` topic however comes with a [caveat](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2358861-assign-a-work-item-to-multiple-people).

**B:** depending on your TFS version, add a [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/add-tags-to-work-items) to the work item. Example "`customer:john.smith`" which can later be queried as [follows](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/2014-jan-22-vso).

Answer (score 1):

Tags are probably the easiest, or on an older TFS if you aren't using area path, then that can also be an easy place to add a customer name.

I would minimise/avoid edits to the tfs templates, as this will make your system "non standard" and will cause you problems when you next want to upgrade your tfs to a newer version or if you want to integrate any third party tools with tfs.